# Как пропорционально растянуть страницы?

Tags: jquery, html, html5, javascript, css

Мне нужно, что бы HTML страница была резиновой т.е. растягивалась бы, но при этом она должна сохранять свои пропорции 3:4. Т.е. она должна не тупо максимально растягиваться во все стороны, что бы заполнить весь экран, а должна растягиваться так, чтобы ещё и сохранить свои пропорции. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

скриптом:

```
$(window).resize(function(){$('body').height(parseInt($('body').width())*0.75)})
```

другого надёжного способа нет.